# parallel to usb driver windows 7 dot matrix printer

Tags: windows-7, printer

I recently built a new Core i5 system with Windows 7 Professional. I had planned to hook up my TVS MSP 250 XL printer using a USB to parallel cable

Once I plug the cable in, Windows 7 recognizes it as an IEEE-1284 controller and automatically installs the appropriate driver. However, in the status window it reports the following:

"USB Printing Support -- Ready to use"
"No Printer Attached -- Ready to use"

When I then go ahead and manually add the printer using the "virtual printer port for USB" I can add the printer seemingly without problem. Once finished, it appears in the Devices and Printers panel. Yet, all attempts to print on this printer fail. It appears that simply no data is sent to the printer (either by programs like word or adobe or by attempting to print a test page.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried selecting LPT1 as the port?

Comment: yeap already tried dat!

Comment: USB-to-LPT cables are not very reliable. As this is a desktop PC, I would strongly suggest using a parallel port card if the motherboard does not have one. They're very cheap and work well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert the cable USB-to-Parallel-IEEE-1284 into a USB2.0 port. Keep in mind that USB 3.0 ports will not work. This is the scenario we have now:

   [image: USB Printing Support]

   - USB Printing Support: is your cable
   - EPSONTM-P2.01 (or whatever you have on your machine) is the printer that is not recognized
2. Double click on EPSONTM-P2.01 (or whatever you have on your machine) > Change settings (with Administration privileges) > Driver > Update Driver > Browse my Computer for Driver Software > Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer > Printers > Generic > generic / Text Only

   [image: Select Driver]

   Of course, feel free to pick up the right driver if you see it.

It's a kind of magic: now the not-recognized USB Printing Support has become a printer. Test it and everything should be fine.